# How snowflake connection can keep alive until all statement are executed?

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

how we can keep snowflake connection alive untill all statement are exceuted

i have below list of queries

```
query_list=[query1,query2,query3]
for query in query_list:
  try:
     con.cursor.execute(query)
  finally:
     con.close()
```

here after executing first query, it throwing

```
snowflake.connector.errors.Databaseerror (250002) connection is closed
```

how can resolve this?

Comment: Try the `client_session_keep_alive` connection parameter. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#connect

Comment: I don't think this is a keep-alive situation.  You are explicitly closing your loop on each iteration with the `finally`.  Move that out of the `finally` and put it at the same level as your `for`.  You want to close the connection at the end of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import snowflake.connector
ctx=snowflake.connector.connect(
user='user',
account='account',
password='pass',
warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
database='db_name',
schema='public',
)
curs=ctx.cursor()
query_list=[q1,q2.q3]
for q in query_list:
     curs.execute(q)
curs.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a property in Snowflake python connector, "CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE" which is used to keep the connection alive as long its active (being used) or idle.

This property can be used at session, user and account level.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-session-keep-alive

But if the user closes the connection explicitly then it will be closed and the connection will not be alive even if you use the above property, so if you want the connection to be alive, do not close it explicitly.

Thanks,
Sujan